# Проблема передачи данных из CheckBox через AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

На странице есть 2 набора чекбоксов и div, в который через аякс должны попадать отфильтрованные данные. Есть кнопка с обработчиком, в котором формируются массивы value из каждого набора checkbox и, по идее, должна происходить передача через ajax в php файл для выборки из БД набора данных. Теперь проблема...

Пока не включил в обработчик строчки с ajax, то все работало нормально - кнопка работала, массивы value формировались нормально и правильно. Как только вставил строчки с аяксом, то кнопка перестала срабатывать, а в 1м наборе checkbox дерево элементов полностью сбивалось.

Что это может быть и где я ошибся?

```
<div class="scroll-div">
<div>
<!-- ПЕРВЫЙ НАБОР ЧЕКБОКСОВ -->
<ul id="tree">
<li><label><input type="checkbox" />Страна</label>
<ul>
<li><label><input name="kurorts_id" type="checkbox" value="1"/>Курорт 1</label></li>
<li><label><input name="kurorts_id" type="checkbox" value="2"/>Курорт 2</label></li>
<li><label><input name="kurorts_id" type="checkbox" value="3"/>Курорт 3</label></li>
<li><label><input name="kurorts_id" type="checkbox" value="4"/>Курорт 4</label></li>
<li><label><input name="kurorts_id" type="checkbox" value="5"/>Курорт 5</label></li>
<li><label><input name="kurorts_id" type="checkbox" value="6"/>Курорт 6</label></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<!-- ВТОРОЙ НАБОР ЧЕКБОКСОВ -->
<div class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="star0" name="hstars" value="0"/><label for="star0">0*</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="star1" name="hstars" value="1"/><label for="star1">1*</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="star2" name="hstars" value="2"/><label for="star2">2*</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="star3" name="hstars" value="3"/><label for="star3">3*</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="star4" name="hstars" value="4"/><label for="star4">4*</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="star5" name="hstars" value="5"/><label for="star5">5*</label>
</div>

<div class="scroll-div">
<div>
<div id='hotel_filter' class="checkbox">
<!-- Сюда через аякс должны вставлять отфильтрованные данные -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button class="blue dark small" onclick="bebebe()">
<img src="images/icons/small/white/bended_arrow_right.png">
<span>Фильтр</span>
</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){$("#tree").Tree(); });

function bebebe() {

var i_kurort = $('input[name=kurorts_id]:checked').map(function(indx, element){
  return $(element).attr("value");
});
var arr_kurort = i_kurort.get(); // Массив value из 1й группы
var i_stars = $('input[name=hstars]:checked').map(function(indx, element){
  return $(element).attr("value");
});
var arr_stars = i_stars.get(); // Массив value из 2й группы
alert(arr_kurort);
alert(arr_stars);

$.ajax({
    url: 'filter_hotel.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { ikurort: arr_kurort; istars: arr_stars },
    success: function(data){$('#hotel_filter').html(data);}
});

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу увидел одну ошибку:

```
data: { ikurort: arr_kurort, istars: arr_stars }, // разделять запятой, а не точкой с запятой
```

Comment: Просто гиганчиское спасибо. Из-за пропущенной мелочи, литр валокардина выпил. Все работает.

Comment: @Trubadan в консоль браузера надо заглядывать для экономии валокардина :) ну и jsHint использовать.